# UsernameToken WS-Security with Apache CXF Annotations (WSS4J)

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

I'm trying to create a "java first" webservice that will use plain and simple UsernameToken WS-Security. I've attempted to follow the examples from CXF. When I query my wsdl I see no mention of anything ws-security related. I'm using CXF 2.7.5 and I'm trying to do everything with annotations.

The following is my failed attempt:

**SampleService.java:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.apache.cxf.annotations.EndpointProperties;
import org.apache.cxf.annotations.EndpointProperty;

@WebService(targetNamespace="https://test.company.com/ws/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@EndpointProperties({
    @EndpointProperty(key = "action", value="UsernameToken"),
    @EndpointProperty(key = "passwordType", value="PasswordText"),
    @EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.callback-handler", value="PasswordHandler"),
    //@EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.validate.token", value="false"),
})
public interface SampleService {

    @WebMethod
    public String getSample(
            @WebParam(name="startDate") Date startDate, 
            @WebParam(name="endDate") Date endDate);

}
```

**SampleServiceImpl.java:**

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "SampleService", targetNamespace="https://test.company.com/ws/")
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public String getSample(Date startDate, Date endDate) {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Start Date: ");
        sb.append(startDate.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("End Date: ");
        sb.append(endDate.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**PasswordHandler.java:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class PasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

    WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

    System.out.println("User: " + pc.getIdentifier());
    System.out.println("Password: " + pc.getIdentifier());
    System.out.println("Type: " + pc.getType());
    if (pc.getIdentifier().equals("joe")) {
        // set the password on the callback. This will be compared to the
        // password which was sent from the client.
        pc.setPassword("password");

    }
}

}
```

**SampleServicePublisher.java:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants;
import org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants;

public class SampleServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String URL = "http://localhost:9999/ws/SampleService";
        EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = 
                    (EndpointImpl) javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(URL, new SampleServiceImpl());
        Endpoint cxfEndpoint = jaxWsEndpoint.getServer().getEndpoint();

        Map<String,Object> inProps= new HashMap<String,Object>();
        // how to configure the properties is outlined below;

        WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
        cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

        Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        // how to configure the properties is outlined below;

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        // Password type : plain text
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
        // for hashed password use:
        //properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_DIGEST);
        // Callback used to retrieve password for given user.
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordHandler.class.getName());
       }
}
```

**mvn dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jetty is needed if you're using the CXFServlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-rm</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-addr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the WS-SecurityPolicy based configuration instead of the WSS4J interceptor approach!

For this create a .wsdl file from your "java first" webservice and extend it with the  and  part and put it anywhere in your project. (f.e. /WEB-INF/wsdl)

```
      ...
      <binding name="SecurityServicePortBinding" type="tns:ServiceIface">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityServiceBindingPolicy"/>
        ....
      </binding>    
      <service name="SecurityService">
        <port name="SecurityServicePort" binding="tns:SecurityServicePortBinding">
          <soap:address location="https://localhost:8443/jaxws-samples-wsse-policy-username"/>
        </port>
      </service>

     <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SecurityServiceBindingPolicy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
           <wsp:All>
              <wsaw:UsingAddressing
                 xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
                 wsp:Optional="true" />
              <sp:TransportBinding>
                 <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                       <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:HttpsToken
                             RequireClientCertificate="false" />
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:Layout>
                       <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:Lax />
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                       <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:Basic128 />
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                 </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:TransportBinding>
              <sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
                 <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                       sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                       <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
                       </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                 </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
              <sp:Wss11 />
           </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
     </wsp:Policy>            
 </definitions>
```

Define the wsdlLocation parameter within the @Webservice annotation and use the @EndpointConfig annotation not @EndpointProperties.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
(
   portName = "SecurityServicePort",
   serviceName = "SecurityService",
   wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/SecurityService.wsdl",
   targetNamespace = "http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/ws-extensions/wssecuritypolicy",
   endpointInterface = "org.jboss.test.ws.jaxws.samples.wsse.policy.wsdl.ServiceIface"
)
@EndpointConfig(configFile = "WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml", configName = "Custom WS-Security Endpoint")
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceIface
{

   public String sayHello()
   {
      return helloservice.sayHello();
   }
}
```

Define your ws-security.callback-handler within the WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jaxws-config xmlns="urn:jboss:jbossws-jaxws-config:4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jbossws-jaxws-config:4.0 schema/jbossws-jaxws-config_4_0.xsd">

  <endpoint-config>
    <config-name>Custom WS-Security Endpoint</config-name>
    <property>
      <property-name>ws-security.callback-handler</property-name>
      <property-value>org.jboss.test.ws.jaxws.samples.wsse.policy.basic.UsernamePasswordCallback</property-value>
    </property>
  </endpoint-config>

</jaxws-config>
```

mvn dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
     <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
     <version>${cxf.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>       
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
     <artifactId>jbossws-native-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Load the org.apache.ws.security JBOSS module:
WEB-INF/jboss-depoyment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.ws.security"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I implemented a helloworld projekt: https://github.com/matyig/wsse-policy-username

If you'd like using a Non-WS-SecurityPolicy approach, you could use the spring xml configuration way. You find a good tutorial here:

http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/cxf_usernametoken_profile

Comment: I don't get one thing why do you need to implement passworld call handler on the client side. The client shouldn't need to worry. How would it work if the client was PHP or .NET ???